# How to interpret logistic regression output?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have the R output for the logistic regression model. It seems that only the intercept and psa are statistically significant. Does that mean I should remove sorbets_psa and cinko from my model and create a new model as `new.model = glm(status ~ psa,family = binomial(link ="probit"))`

```
Call:
glm(formula = status ~ psa + serbest_psa + cinko, family = binomial(link ="probit"), 
data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.3285  -0.6773  -0.6261  -0.5604   1.9500  

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.9697009  0.2409856  -4.024 5.72e-05 ***
psa          0.0444376  0.0094368   4.709 2.49e-06 ***
serbest_psa -0.0440718  0.0250486  -1.759   0.0785 .  
cinko       -0.0006923  0.0016984  -0.408   0.6835    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 534.27  on 477  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 477.07  on 474  degrees of freedom
AIC: 485.07

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

Comment: Your question really depends on your objective, as -in real life- there are no correct models, but correct methods for your objective. So, is your objective predictive capability? interpretation? create a good story to say based on your insights? limit the number of input variables? The info you get here is just that in the presence of "psa" the other 2 variables don't have a major influence.

Comment: I am interested in what influences the response variable actually. I suppose in this case it is only psa, right?

Comment: Hmmm. In this case -and I mean this combination of variables- that's the main insight you get. However, each of those variables separately might influence your response variable. Is that something you want to know? If yes, run 3 different `y~x` models for each input variable. Are you interested in interactions maybe? Try `y~x1*x2` for each pair. Lots of things to investigate as you can combine your variables in various different ways.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The number of independent variables in your model should depend on the number of degrees of freedom available, the multicollinearity of the independent variables, and the fit of the model.  This isn't really an R programming question, however, so you may want to ask it over on Cross Validated.